# InkToolbar breaks VS2015 Designer with error Element not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I've created blank UWP app using VS2015 Update3 and when I add `InkCanvas` control to the page, I'm getting this error in VS Designer. The app compiles and runs just fine.

[image]

even when I remove TargetInkCanvas, the error remains. Element with name inkCanvas exists on the page, of course

How to fix the designer and xaml editor?

Comment: This is a known issue. Look [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5d4b6c7-58af-493e-821a-6e62af64d9a4/uwpxaml-inktoolbar-element-not-found?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: unfortunatelly, it does not help. probably it is and old workaround not complatible with Aniversary update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JayZuo and @tao mentioned, it is a known bug that is being worked on.

meanwhile I've come with workaround:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="inkToolbarPlaceholder" />
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
      InkToolbar inkToolbar;
      public MainPage()
      {
          this.InitializeComponent();
          //create InkToolbar right after InitializeComponent call
          inkToolbar = new InkToolbar();
          inkToolbar.TargetInkCanvas = inkCanvas;
          inkToolbarPlaceholder.Content = inkToolbar;
      } 
 }
```

Comment: Do we need to add additional options for this to work? There are no visible controls when I put the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue for XAML designer, for now you can safely ignore this error.

Ref [Windows Ink 1: Introduction to Ink and Pen](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/11/21/windows-ink-1-introduction-to-ink-and-pen/) blog:

> **Note: If you see a XAML designer error when you add the InkToolbar, you can safely ignore this as it is a known issue that is being worked on. Your code will run fine.**

Comment: Well, if it breaks my designer I can't ignore it, because I want to use the designer. I would accept this as an answer, but it is missing some workaround

Comment: @Liero Unfortunately there is no workaround for this issue now. This is a  XAML designer issue. Usually we need a Visual Studio update to fix it. I would update my answer once the issue is fixed. Thanks for your feedback. ;)